# Game controller button colours database?

Tags: library, c

Is there a **database** of game controllers and button *colours*?

For example, something that lists that the Xbox 360 controller's A button is green, or the SNES controller's B button is yellow.

For developing video games that support generic game controllers, I'd like to display help text like "press X to start", but this can be improved if the button name is in the same colour as the button itself.

For example, for SDL2 there is a [community-sourced database of button *names*](https://github.com/gabomdq/SDL_GameControllerDB), which gives the names of buttons (e.g. A, B) instead of just button numbers (e.g. 0, 1); I'm looking for something analogous but for button colours.

Although my platform is SDL, any other format is fine as long as I can export and build a mapping to suit my needs.